# Select2 mutiple selection can select only continues value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-select2

I have one reuqirement in select2 multiple that user can select only continues values only

e.g.:- have values
1
2
3
4
5

So if user select 2 than he select 3 only not 4 or 5.

So it is possible?

Comment: Please describe your question briefly.

Comment: There are one select2 deopdown and user can select multiple values but i want is user can select values continuesly

e.g.:-  dropdown having values
1
2
3
4
5

Than if user selct 2 than he can only able to select 3, like that.

Comment: If options like "a, b,c, m, d, g" then you want users can select in the same order. For example, if the user selects option "a" then select option "b" and then select option "g". So in this case, option "g" should not be selected?

Comment: probably better ask here: https://forums.select2.org/c/how-do-i/5